# How can I reload the page after redirect to the link in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom. When I click the link it redirect to the same page.
why it doesn't just "go" to that link? Here is my code.

```
<Link to="/blog-list" onClick={() => window.location.reload()}>Blog List</Link>
```

How can I reload and also go to that link?

Comment: why don't use anchor tag instead of Link component?

Comment: how to use anchoe tag? please help. Is it possible in react?

Comment: <a href="/blog-list">Blog List </a>

Comment: I want to reload to load a component. How can I do that?

Comment: <a href="/blog-list">Blog List </a> It does not solve my problem.

Comment: <Link to="/blog-list" >Blog List</Link>. Have you tried this beacause Link reloads the whole page.

Comment: <Link to="/blog-list" >Blog List</Link> It does not reload, I want to reload to load a component. Yeah I tried it

Comment: I think anchor tag should have worked, can you create an example on codesandbox.io ? try this too : <div onClick={() => {window.location.href="/blog-list"}>Blog List </div>

Comment: yeah It works properly now. Thanks a lot